# Join types in Power BI designer

Tags: data-modeling, powerbi

How can we specify left/right joins when specifying relationships between tables in Power BI desktop? i am not referring to merging of tables but setting up joins between tables under "manager relationship" tab.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked under the Advanced Options section in the Create Relationship or Edit Relationship dialogs? You can specify the cardinality and the cross filter direction of the relationship.